# Gmail IMAP search by UID range seems to skip the first message

Tags: gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I have a mailbox on gmail that has the following UIDs if I do a search 'ALL'.

```
[ 2, 5, 6, 51 ]
```

Oddly, if I do a search for '3:*', I only get [6, 51] back.

```
==> A6 UID SEARCH 3:*
<== '* SEARCH 6 51\r\nA6 OK SEARCH completed (Success)\r\n'
[parsing incoming] saw untagged SEARCH
<== 'A6 OK SEARCH completed (Success)\r\n'
```

From my understanding of IMAP, it is supposed to return [5, 6, 51] right?  Is this a bug with Gmail or just my incorrect understandging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `UID SEARCH UID 3:*`.  You're searching by message sequence numbers.  1 -> 2, 2 -> 5, 3 -> 6, 4 -> 51.  So you're searching for messages 3 and 4, which have UIDs 6, and 51.

Comment: Thanks, what confused me was needing the extra `UID` before the range